# codeigniter / groceryCRUD send data to view not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a script that works, this one:

```
    $output = $crud->render();

    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = 'Invoice details';
    $output->data = $data;

    $this->output($output); /* crud render and extra fields */
```

the thing is that this script is opening a function in the controler:

```
    public function output($output = null) {
    $this->load->view('template.php', $output);
}
```

and the template file as this: (and more)

```
<title><?php echo ucfirst($data['title']); ?></title>
```

works like a charm.

the template file is loading the header and footer and a bunch of css

when I want to open the invoice, I don't want to open the template, just invoice.php

so I created this:

```
    public function invoice_print() {
    $data = array();
    $data['company'] = 'test';

    $this->load->view('invoice.php', $data);
}
```

when I open the page I get a error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: data
>   Filename: views/invoice.php
>   Line Number: 16

invoice.php line 16 = this:

```
<p class="bold"> <?php echo $data['company']; ?> </p>
```

how do I fix this?

regards,

Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the variable to the view, you call the variable by the index:

```
$data['company'] = 'test';
$this->load->view('invoice.php', $data);
```

view:

```
<p class="bold"> <?php echo $company; ?> </p>
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you, but what I don't understand the difference between my first example that works, and suddenly in this example it doesn't work and I need to use the index. how come?

Comment: Because you are using the [`output`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/output.html) class in the first example. In the second, you are using the `Loader` class which in the case of `load->view` sends data to the output class which creates the variable from the `$data` array index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = $crud->render();
$misDatos =  'Invoice details';
$output->misDatos = $misDatos;
$this->_example_output($output);
```

And you print `$misDatos` in your VIEW.